# How do I update the contents of a file before reading it?

Tags: java, excel, csv, combobox, filereader

I am coding a program that requires me to be able to write the personal details of people to an excel file. I must be able to then read the contents of this file and present them in a combo box. However currently if I run the program and enter the details of a person, then use the combo box to select one of these people, anybody entered on the current run-through of the program will not be shown in the combo box. If I close the program and run it again, however, they will then appear. How can I fix this?

```
String csvFile = "Clients.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";
        String fullName = null;

        try {
            File file = new File("Clients.csv");
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] data = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                fullName = data[0]+" "+data[1];
                comboBox_1.addItem(fullName);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        //FILE READING END
        comboBox_1.setBounds(130, 25, 584, 20);
        existingClients.add(comboBox_1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your program, your BufferedReader is fed with the csv file with current data in it. In run time your program doesn't know whether you entered new entries in your csv file.

You should write a block of code which updates the csv file when you hit the "Add Person" button(or whatever you call it in your program), then triggers a new BufferedReader.

Edit:

I don't know your program is a gui or a console application, but I will try to explain as if we are talking about a gui.

Step - 1 --> When the user fills the details of a new person in a textarea in your program, or when s/he hits the "Add Person" button, you should store the details of this person.

Step - 2 -->Then you must create a writer instance. This instance must append new data to your csv file;

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(csvFile));
writer.write("\n" + newPersonDataasString + "\n");
```

Step - 3 -->Finally, you must read your file again using a new BufferedReader fed with your csv file.

as exe-cute-table mentioned, wrapping these steps into custom methods like readFile(), writeFile() is a good solution for maintaining purposes.

Let me now if I misdirected you.

Comment: I am unsure on how to update the file, or where to add a new BufferedReader.

Comment: Editted my answer.

Comment: Right, so you say I need a new BufferedReader, so do you mean I need 2, or just have one after writing to the file?

Comment: I guess you have to create two instances.[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086500/how-can-i-read-the-same-file-two-times-in-java) should help.

Comment: I am struggling to understand what you mean, is it not possible for you to edit my code to show me?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you write in your file, you have to open it again (with the BufferedReader as you did) too see the changes. The BufferedReader, once created, won't store the new changes of your CSV file.

So the best way is to have two functions:

- `readFile(filename)` which will read the file using the `BufferedReader` (which is created, used and closed)
- `writeFile(filename, contentToWrite)` which will write into the file using the `BufferedWriter` (which is also created, used and closed)

Each time you add a person, call `writeFile("your.csv", your_data)`.
Each time you want to display the datas from your csv (e.g listing all people stored in), call `readFile("your.csv")`

Comment: I do not quite understand how to apply what you are telling me.

Comment: Simply said, you can't use ONLY ONE instance of BufferedReader to read your file and to see the changes you've made in this file. Each time your CSV is edited, you have to open it again (the code you exactly put in your question). That means that you need to create the BufferedReader, read the lines (br.readLine), store the datas into values and close it.

I suggested you to create two functions because it seems that you are reading and writing in your CSV file many times.

Comment: So where does each BufferedReader come?

Comment: Each time you read your CSV file.
If you need to display the data of your CSV file, create the BufferedReader, read the data and store them in a variable (array, ArrayList, ...), and close it. Then do some stuff (for example write a new person in the file). And then when you want to display the data again WITH the changes, do the same thing: create a buffer, read the data, store them in a variable and close the buffer. You can do this by creating a function that does this process and return an array (or ArrayList, whatever you prefer). Each time you need to read the data, call this function.

Comment: this may help you, i'm too lazy to write code for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086500/how-can-i-read-the-same-file-two-times-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1